# HAproxy: Accept only localhost requests

Tags: localhost, server, haproxy

I have a backend server running for which HAproxy is the load balancer. The configuration which redirects to the respective server from haproxy is:

```
acl use_be_server hdr(host) -i beserver.com

use_backend beserver if use_be_server    

backend beserver
    server  my_server   127.0.0.1:8001
```

Now, beserver.com is used **only from localhost** and should not be accessed from else where for security reasons.

My question is, can I configure HAproxy to accept requests only from localhost for this port number?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ACL to filter the `src` IP.

In this example, it checks whether the IP is in the `white_list` and `host` is beserver.com.

```
acl white_list src 127.0.0.1
acl use_be_server hdr(host) -i beserver.com
use_backend beserver if { white_list } { use_be_server }
```